# One variable not evolving properly in simulation of particles orbiting a central mass

Tags: python

I'm attempting to build a model of 12 particles in a circular orbit around a central mass. I've done this by creating an array which contains the positions and velocities of the particles, and then using odeint to integrate the equations of motion. When I run the program, I appear to get the correct evolution for the value of y for each particle, but not for the value of x. My array, called cond, stores the information about the system in the format [x1,y1,z1,vx1,vy1,vz1, x2] and so on. This is my code:

```
#project starts here
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import pi
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from math import sqrt

G=1
M=1
N=12
def deriv(cond,t,G,M):
    for q in range (0,12):
        i=6*q
        dydt = list(range(72))
        dydt[i]=cond[i+3]
        dydt[i+1]=cond[i+4]
        dydt[i+2]=cond[i+5]
        r=sqrt((cond[i])**2 +(cond[i+1])**2 +(cond[i+2])**2)
        dydt[i+3]=-G*M*cond[i]/(r**3)
        dydt[i+4]=-G*M*cond[i+1]/(r**3)
        dydt[i+5]=-G*M*cond[i+2]/(r**3)
    return dydt


vmag=((G*M)/2)**(0.5)
theta = np.linspace(0,2*pi,N)
x=2*np.cos(theta)
y=2*np.sin(theta)
vx=-vmag*np.sin(theta)
vy=vmag*np.cos(theta)
z=np.zeros(N)
vz=np.zeros(N)
t=np.linspace(0,30,100)

cond=list(item for group in zip(x,y,z,vx,vy,vz) for item in group)
sln=odeint(deriv, cond, t, args=(G,M))

print(sln)
```

The output I get is x staying constant at a value 2 (its starting value). y evolves constantly with time, as you would expect. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried to plot part of the trajectories on a graph? I noticed you imported `matplotlib` but didn't use it...

Comment: I wrote a program like this as a teenager. You really don't want to 'integrate the equations of motion' - instead make it numerical. Specify a time period, move each particle according to its velocity, mass and attractions; then repeat. This is how NASA does it, according to a documentary I saw once.